# Use of simple present vs. present perfect to announce something

Tags: tense

> "The car **is sold** for thirty thousand euros," the auctioneer said.

Vs

> "The car **has been sold** for thirty thousand euros," the auctioneer said.

Also

> You **are** fired.

Vs

> You **have been** fired.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

It's a distinction of **precise moment**.

As the auctioneer bangs his gavel to signify the end of the sale, he will announce that

> "The car is sold for €30,000"

At any time after that, he would have to say

> "The car has been [*or* was] sold for €30,000"

Similarly, as you are standing in front of the boss's desk, he tells you

> "You are fired."

As you leave the office, one of your colleagues guesses at what he saw just happen

> You have been fired.